# Java Ticketing system error on last two lines

Tags: java, parsing, compiler-errors

I have been fighting with this for quite a while and in th eend I took all the errors away but I do not seem to be able to get why the last two errors appear.

Here are the errors:

I keep getting these:

java:101: error: while expected
  }

java:102: error: reached end of file while parsing
}

```
 {


BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));



   String people;
   int tickets;                 // here we start setting all the variables
   char ticketloop;
   double price;
   String movie, surname;
   price = 20.00;
   tickets = 0;
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  {

   System.out.println("Please enter surname of patron: ");
   Scanner surnameScan = new Scanner(System.in);
   surname = surnameScan.nextLine();
   }
   {
   System.out.println("Please enter name of the show: ");
   Scanner movieScan = new Scanner(System.in);
   movie = movieScan.nextLine();
   }
   {
   System.out.println("Please enter number of people: ");
   int x= Integer; parseInt (people); //converting people string into an integer
   people = bReader.readLine();

   }
   {
   while(people <0 || people >10)
   {
   System.out.println("Wait, way to many people!");    // I just use this in case th euser puts more than 10 users
   Scanner peopleScan = new Scanner(System.in);
   people = peopleScan.nextLine();                                                      // User Input
   }

   tickets = tickets + 1;                         // Adds 1 to counter

   if(people >6)
   price=20.00-(20.00/100)*10;                                // Uses discount price if there are more than 6 people
   else
   price=20.00;                                            // If less than 6, then does not use the discount

   System.out.println("Movie       : " +movie);                  // Prints show name entered by user on the screen
   System.out.println("Surname    : " +surname);               // Prints the surname entered by user on the screen
   System.out.println("How many are you: " +people);                // Prints the number of people entered by user on the screen

   if(people >6)                                                // If statement

   System.out.println("Final Price: " +price*people);  // If number of people is bigger than 6 it prints out 10% DISCOUNT message and calculates total cost


   else                                                      // Else statement


   System.out.println("Final Price       : " +price*people);          // If number of people is less than 6 calculates total cost and prints the result on the screen
   System.out.println("Want more tickets? Enter 'y' / 'n' and press <enter>");      // Prompts user for input
   System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
   Scanner ticketloopScan = new Scanner(System.in);
   Char ticketloop = ticketloopScan.nextLine();                               // User input

   while(ticketloop !='y' && ticketloop !='n')    // While loop to determine if the user entered a value outside the given options
   {
   System.out.println("That's not right! Enter y or n");   // Prints this if user enters an invalid input
   Scanner ticketloopScan = new Scanner(System.in);
   String ticketloop = ticketoopScan.nextLine();                             // User input
   }


   while(ticketloop =='y');                 // do/while structure
   if(ticketloop =='n')                      // If comparison operator


   System.out.println("Total number of tickets processed: " + tickets);    // Prints out number of total tickets processed before quitting
   System.out.println("Have a nice day! "
   }


}
```

}

Comment: How many spaces did you use for the indentation ? My guess is about 45. Just by looking at your error I can say you are missing a closing curly bracket or something like that.

Comment: Looks like a problem with your bracket matching. It would be easier to deduce with better formatting.

Comment: You have a missing closing `}` or an extra `{` somewhere. Any decent IDE will show you where.

Comment: many, I'm just starting with java, first assignment and I wanted to keep indentation very clear :) you are right, maaaany spaces.

Comment: This line `String movie, surname;{` looks suspicious. Is the `{` at the end intended?

Comment: @Onteo I don't find this "very clear". Indent your code with 2,3 or 4 spaces.

Comment: Apologies for the first try at posting code. first timer :(

Answer (score 0):

```
String movie, surname;{
```

What is a curly bracket doing here ? Remove it.

Comment: strange, that curly bracket does not appear in my code.String people;
             int tickets;                 // here we start setting all the variables
                               char ticketloop;
                               double price;
                               String movie, surname;
                               price = 20.00;
                               tickets = 0;
                               Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: Reformat your code, make it clean, and you will never have that kind of problems anymore.

Comment: Your code is still a mess, and this is an infinite loop (or a loop that is never executed) : `while(ticketloop =='y');`. Plus, you have curly brackets at random places in your code when there is absolutely no reason to have a block. You really need to be more organized if you want to program.

Comment: indeed it was a big mess, I have changed it almost in every aspect and now it runs well. I'm just missing the bit on how to loop the program in case the user wants more tickets. thank you dici.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my code big time, still a few errors, but it runs.

```
BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   int people, tickets;                 // here we start setting all the variables
   double price;
   String movie, surname;
   price = 20.00;
   tickets = 0;

   {
   Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter surname of patron: ");
   surname = sc1.nextLine ();

   }
   {
   Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter name of the movie: ");
   movie = sc2.nextLine ();
   }
   {
   Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please enter number of people: ");
   people = sc3.nextInt ();



   }
   {
   while(people <0 || people >10)
   {
   System.out.println("Wait, way to many people!");    // I just use this in case th euser puts more than 10 users
   Scanner sc4 = new Scanner(System.in);
   people = sc4.nextInt();                                                      // User Input
   }

   tickets = tickets + 1;                         // Adds 1 to counter

   if(people >6)
   price=20.00-(20.00/100)*10;                                // Uses discount price if there are more than 6 people
   else
   price=20.00;                                            // If less than 6, then does not use the discount


   System.out.println("Movie       : " +movie);                  // Prints show name entered by user on the screen
   System.out.println("Surname    : " +surname);               // Prints the surname entered by user on the screen
   System.out.println("How many are you: " +people);                // Prints the number of people entered by user on the screen


   if(people >6)                                                // If statement

   System.out.println("Final Price: " +price*people);  // If number of people is bigger than 6 it prints out 10% DISCOUNT message and calculates total cost


   else                                                      // Else statement


   System.out.println("Final Price       : " +price*people);          // If number of people is less than 6 calculates total cost and prints the result on the screen
   System.out.println("Want more tickets? Enter 'y' / 'n' and press <enter>");      // Prompts user for input
   System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
   Scanner sc5 = new Scanner(System.in);
   char ticketloop;
   ticketloop = sc5.next().charAt(0);                               // User input



   while(ticketloop !='y' && ticketloop !='n')    // While loop to determine if the user entered a value outside the given options


   {
   System.out.println("That's not right! Enter y or n");   // Prints this if user enters an invalid input
   Scanner sc6 = new Scanner(System.in);
   char yesorno;
   yesorno = sc6.next().charAt(0);
                         // User input
   }


   while(ticketloop =='y');                 // do/while structure
   if(ticketloop =='n')                      // If comparison operator


   System.out.println("Total number of tickets processed: " + tickets);    // Prints out number of total tickets processed before quitting
   System.out.println("Have a nice day! ");
   }
}
```

}